# How to scroll a div up and down using/via a draggable object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-draggable

What i want to do is to control / scroll a div up and down and its movement depends on the dragged object. This drag object is of type draggable in jQuery.

e.g. When i drag the object upwards, the div scrolls up and vice versa.

dragged object is the joystick

```
$("#joystick").draggable({
        revert: true,
        containment: "parent",
        create: function(){
           $(this).data("startLeft",parseInt($(this).css("left")));
           $(this).data("startTop",parseInt($(this).css("top")));
        },
        start: function() {
            animating = true;
        },
        drag: function(event,ui){
            var rel_left = ui.position.left - parseInt($(this).data("startLeft"));
            var rel_top = ui.position.top - parseInt($(this).data("startTop"));
            animate(rel_top)
        },
        stop: function(){
            animating = false;
        },
        axis : "y"
    });
```

animate function

```
var animate = function(r){
        $("#timeline").stop().animate({ scrollTop : r },2000,function(){
            if( animating ){
                animate(r);
            }
        })
    }
```

also, this div is scrolled down onload

```
$("#timeline").animate({ scrollTop: $('#timeline')[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);
```

example here : http://jsfiddle.net/wq4Lg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i found the answer, i modified the animate() function.

```
var s = (r > 0) ? -10 : $("#timeline")[0].scrollHeight;
```

if r is negative, i'll scroll the div up and down if positive and also added

```
$("#timeline").stop();
```

in the stop() method inside draggable.